# Accordion input ::before pseudo element

Tags: css, accordion

I have an accordion menu which I believe uses a checkbox to activeate and deactivate the expand and it uses the below css to transform the arrows based on whether it is expanded or not.

```
.expand input + *::before {
content: '»';
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 25px;
padding-right: 18px;
padding-top: 0;
float: left;
transition: all 0.2s;
margin-top: -5px;
}

.expand input:checked + *::before {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

The problem I have is that I am using checkboxes in `<li>` elements within the accordion and not want the above styles applied to those checkboxes.

I can't seem to find a way around this though.

EDIT** I realised i was over complication this way too much, I have since removed the list item which expands and used the react bootstrap accordion which expands without the use if a checkbox.

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your code

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can see it in action?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi, Im not sure I can, as this is a react.js based webapp.

Answer (score 0):

You can namespace the checkboxes by given it a class like input.checkbox-hack:checked